# How to Extract a string after a variable number of characters in EXCEL?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I'm pretty sure you can do this easier in VB, but Im looking to do this with formulas in EXCEL.

I would like to strip off the first x number of 'part's in a given string within EXCEL.  A 'part' is a split of the full string.

EXAMPLE In C#:

```
"A.BB.CCC.DDDD.EEEEE".Split(new char[]{'.'});
// This yields 5 parts, "A", "BB", "CCC", "DDDD", "EEEEE"
```

So I need a formula that would take in '2', and would yield CCC.DDDD.EEEEE, by stripping off the first 2 'part's of the string.

```
A.BB.CCC.DDDD.EEEEE --> CCC.DDDD.EEEEE given 2
A.BB.CCC.DDDD.EEEEE --> DDDD.EEEEE given 3
A.BB.CCC.DDDD.EEEEE --> A.BB.CCC.DDDD.EEEEE given 0
```

Comment: I'm confused on what you are asking exactly. Can you lay out your question better?

Comment: How are you given the number of given `.`?

Comment: Updated the question to try to explain better, help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you could use:

```
=MID(A2, FIND("@", SUBSTITUTE(A2, ".", "@", 2))+1, LEN(A2))
                                            ^
```

The one I pointed above is what states the 'given'. Put 2 for 2 `.` and 3 for 3 `.`.

Or reference it to a cell where you'll get to know how many dots you need.

EDIT: As per edit in question, we could add an `IF()` to check for `0`. Let's say that the number is stored in cell A1:

```
=IF(A1 = 0, A2, MID(A2, FIND("@", SUBSTITUTE(A2, ".", "@", A1))+1, LEN(A2)))
```

Comment: Although this solves my immediate need, there is no guarantee that a '@' wont be in my original string ... infact any character could be in the string (except for '.', which is the seperator)  +1 anyways, but not the perfect solution!

Comment: @Tizz You can use `CHAR(1)` instead, which should be less common than `@` :)

Comment: Interesting ... I suppose CHAR(1) would never be typed ;)  I think you've sold me now! :)

Comment: @Tizz Also, as per your update, I guess one could add an `IF()` to check for the value. Updated.

Answer (score 0):

After two dots:

`=MID(B5,SEARCH(".",B5,SEARCH(".",B5)+1)+1,100)`

Comment: @Jerry's is better...

Comment: This solves the inherent issue with @Jerry's solution, however, what if I want to strip off 100 parts?  Thats a lot of cut and pasting...

Comment: Yes - that's why Jerry's is better...  Seems like a good candidate for a VBA user-defined function though.